# Spark / PySpark - Cannot get return values from Spark Cluster on Docker

Tags: python, docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two docker containers running:

```
172.22.0.3 spark-worker-1
172.22.0.2 spark-master
```

Inside the master container I execute a simple python script to test functionality.
When accessing Spark Master UI I can see the worker being connected and ALIVE, I can see the Application appears under "Running Applications" and moved to "Completed Applications" with State "FINISHED" when script has executed.

Issue : I cannot receive the value (df.show()) with below log. The code works well when not connecting to master in SparkSession. The container has enough CPU/MEM (and the job is minimal).
I'm running out of ideas for resolving this, anyone with input?

Python code:

```
import pyspark
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
        .appName("dev_sparkTest")\
        .master("spark://172.22.0.2:7077")\
        .getOrCreate()

pdf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": [np.random.randint(10) for x in range(10)],
        "col2": [np.random.randint(100) for x in range(10)],
    }
)
df = spark.createDataFrame(pdf)
df.show()
```

Output from Python script:

```
/ # python3 sparkTest.py
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
22/05/30 13:08:09 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
22/05/30 13:08:14 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 0 on 172.22.0.3: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
22/05/30 13:08:14 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (172.22.0.3 executor 0): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 0 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
22/05/30 13:08:16 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on 172.22.0.3: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
22/05/30 13:08:16 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (172.22.0.3 executor 1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 1 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
22/05/30 13:08:19 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 2 on 172.22.0.3: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
22/05/30 13:08:19 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) (172.22.0.3 executor 2): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 2 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
22/05/30 13:08:21 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 3 on 172.22.0.3: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
22/05/30 13:08:21 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (172.22.0.3 executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
22/05/30 13:08:21 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sparkTest.py", line 19, in <module>
    df.show()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 494, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o46.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) (172.22.0.3 executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:476)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:429)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3715)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2728)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3706)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3704)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2728)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2935)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:326)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Log from spark-worker-1 container:

```
22/05/30 13:08:10 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/spark/conf/:/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=41589" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@0f53b6eaef4e:41589" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "172.22.0.3" "--cores" "16" "--app-id" "app-20220530130810-0005" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.22.0.3:36935"

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO Worker: Executor app-20220530130810-0005/0 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 50 exitStatus 50

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 0

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-20220530130810-0005, execId=0)

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20220530130810-0005/1 for dev_sparkTest

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/spark/conf/:/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=41589" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@0f53b6eaef4e:41589" "--executor-id" "1" "--hostname" "172.22.0.3" "--cores" "16" "--app-id" "app-20220530130810-0005" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.22.0.3:36935"

22/05/30 13:08:16 INFO Worker: Executor app-20220530130810-0005/1 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 50 exitStatus 50

22/05/30 13:08:16 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 1

22/05/30 13:08:16 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-20220530130810-0005, execId=1)

22/05/30 13:08:17 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20220530130810-0005/2 for dev_sparkTest

22/05/30 13:08:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root

22/05/30 13:08:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root

22/05/30 13:08:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 

22/05/30 13:08:17 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 

22/05/30 13:08:17 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()

22/05/30 13:08:17 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/spark/conf/:/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=41589" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@0f53b6eaef4e:41589" "--executor-id" "2" "--hostname" "172.22.0.3" "--cores" "16" "--app-id" "app-20220530130810-0005" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.22.0.3:36935"

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO Worker: Executor app-20220530130810-0005/2 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 50 exitStatus 50

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 2

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-20220530130810-0005, execId=2)

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20220530130810-0005/3 for dev_sparkTest

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/spark/conf/:/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=41589" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@0f53b6eaef4e:41589" "--executor-id" "3" "--hostname" "172.22.0.3" "--cores" "16" "--app-id" "app-20220530130810-0005" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.22.0.3:36935"

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Worker: Executor app-20220530130810-0005/3 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 50 exitStatus 50

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 3

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-20220530130810-0005, execId=3)

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Worker: Asked to launch executor app-20220530130810-0005/4 for dev_sparkTest

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO ExecutorRunner: Launch command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/spark/conf/:/spark/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=41589" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@0f53b6eaef4e:41589" "--executor-id" "4" "--hostname" "172.22.0.3" "--cores" "16" "--app-id" "app-20220530130810-0005" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@172.22.0.3:36935"

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Worker: Asked to kill executor app-20220530130810-0005/4

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO ExecutorRunner: Runner thread for executor app-20220530130810-0005/4 interrupted

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO ExecutorRunner: Killing process!

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Worker: Executor app-20220530130810-0005/4 finished with state KILLED exitStatus 143

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Clean up non-shuffle and non-RDD files associated with the finished executor 4

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Executor is not registered (appId=app-20220530130810-0005, execId=4)

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Worker: Cleaning up local directories for application app-20220530130810-0005

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO ExternalShuffleBlockResolver: Application app-20220530130810-0005 removed, cleanupLocalDirs = true
```

Log from spark-master container:

```
22/05/30 13:08:10 INFO Master: Registering app dev_sparkTest

22/05/30 13:08:10 INFO Master: Registered app dev_sparkTest with ID app-20220530130810-0005

22/05/30 13:08:10 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20220530130810-0005/0 on worker worker-20220530130245-172.22.0.3-36935

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20220530130810-0005/0 because it is EXITED

22/05/30 13:08:14 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20220530130810-0005/1 on worker worker-20220530130245-172.22.0.3-36935

22/05/30 13:08:16 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20220530130810-0005/1 because it is EXITED

22/05/30 13:08:16 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20220530130810-0005/2 on worker worker-20220530130245-172.22.0.3-36935

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20220530130810-0005/2 because it is EXITED

22/05/30 13:08:19 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20220530130810-0005/3 on worker worker-20220530130245-172.22.0.3-36935

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Master: Removing executor app-20220530130810-0005/3 because it is EXITED

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Master: Launching executor app-20220530130810-0005/4 on worker worker-20220530130245-172.22.0.3-36935

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Master: Received unregister request from application app-20220530130810-0005

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Master: Removing app app-20220530130810-0005

22/05/30 13:08:21 WARN Master: Got status update for unknown executor app-20220530130810-0005/4

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Master: 172.22.0.2:56308 got disassociated, removing it.

22/05/30 13:08:21 INFO Master: 0f53b6eaef4e:41589 got disassociated, removing it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check those containers in same docker network?

If you run spark on docker-compose, try use container name instead of ip address.